# Do I need to issue netplan apply after netplan try?

Tags: networking, netplan

I know that netplan try has the automatic revert, but are there any other differences? Specifically, is it required to run
netplan apply
after I confirm
netplan try
?

Comment: If you've made any changes in your .yaml file, then yes. The sequence should always be: edit the .yaml, `sudo netplan generate`, `sudo netplan try` if you wish, and `sudo netplan apply`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to run `netplan apply` or `netplan generate` after you confirmed/accepted a config. The `netplan try` command will do all of that for you in the background.

It only provides the additional safety feature of reverting the change if you don't like that config or somehow locked yourself out of a remote server.